# Is there a library for OAuth 2 in VB

Tags: oauth, vbscript, vb6, iis-6, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement OAuth 2 connectivity for an old site that's implemented in ASP over IIS 6 with VB (not VB.net)

I tried to find a library that implements OAuth 2 and could not find one. Is there such a library? If not, what are my options?

Sorry if the question is trivial, I'm new to VB...

Comment: Find a .Net library and create a COM-visible library, using VB.Net or C#, that is a simple wrapper for the .Net library? That would be callable from VBScript / VB6

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the ignorance. Is that something trivial to do?

Comment: I can't help with any details, but are you trying to implement the server or the client end?

Comment: Taking a .NET library and throwing a wrapper around it may not make for an easy solution.  The .NET library is likely to expose types that VB6 cannot easily consume (e.g. typed lists).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this?](http://scottdesapio.com/VBScriptOAuth/)

This library should help you get started on using OAuth in VBS. Everything you need to get is from [here](http://scottdesapio.com/VBScriptOAuth/oAuthASPExample.zip), place the OAuth folder into your project, then just follow the code samples provided.

Although he is using Twitter for his example, it can be used for any service that supports OAuth.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. As far as I can tell this is OAuth and not OAuth2. Thanks for your answer.